# Sharing power point deck with additional plug-in

Tags: plugins, powerpoint

I have created an interactive PowerPoint presentation with the help of LiveSlides plugin. Can the same deck be viewed in another system without the installation of the plugin and not losing any element of interaction? I don't have another system to check but I need to be assured of this before sharing. I have two intuitions for the answers:

1. Deck will lose the interactive element if the plugin is uninstalled as plugin code has enabled the PowerPoint to add more elements.
2. Deck will remain the same without the plugin as the plugin will add in the metadata of the graph like bokeh add javascript element in matplotlib graphs.

Surely, Uninstalling the deck will clear the doubt but am I missing something to understand the working of the plugin with powerpoints.

Comment: This forum is for programming questions. Uninstall the add-in temporarily and test.

Comment: @JohnKorchok I am trying the understand the architecture of the plugin software. How do they work in the background? I have added more details to the question.

Comment: Here is the LiveSlides FAQ page to answer your questions: https://www.liveslides.com/faq